# Judge the amount of money to trade

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-analysis, day-trading

I have been day trading for about a year. I got some statistics on a stock market pattern. The latter gives me an 82% probability of occurring and an expected gain of 13% per trade. I'm having trouble judging how much stock to buy based on X amount of money to maximize my profit. I had thought of using Kelly's criterion, but I'm not sure if it works in day trading. Can you give me a formula or advice for how many shares I should buy per trade? In general, my pattern works well, but I feel like I could greatly increase my profit per trade.

Comment: How much do you lose in case the trade fails?